# phpPgAdmin 5.6 for Debian

Tags: linux, debian, php, postgresql

I saw phpPgAdmin 5.6 for PostgreSQL is released, but I can only install the 5.1 on Debian 9.

I look for the package:

```
apt search phppgadmin
```

And just get:

```
phppgadmin/stable,now 5.1+ds-2 all
  web-based administration tool for PostgreSQL
```

Only shows me the 5.1 version.

Anybody knows how to pack the latest version of phpPgAdmin for Debian based distros?

Comment: Distributions package these things for you; you want to get the latest *packaged* version of the software, or download & configure it yourself?

Comment: Do you absolutely require features in 5.6 that 5.1 is lacking? Is there some incompatibility with your application that requires 5.6? [Officially](http://phppgadmin.sourceforge.net/doku.php?id=download#debian_packages) 5.1 is the latest version of PHPPgadmin for Debian.

Answer (score 0):

You can download the compressed application from

http://phppgadmin.sourceforge.net/doku.php?id=download

Extract and move to apache web applications directory (/var/www/html/) and copy config file sample

```
cp conf/config.inc.php-dist conf/config.inc.php
```

You need to have apache2 php and php-pgsql installed